# Installing tidyverse on Ubuntu 18.x & R 3.4.4/3.5.1

Tags: r, tidyverse, ubuntu-18.04

I attempted to install tidyverse (and the packages that make up tidyverse) and got the following output:

```
> install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/aos11409/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/dbplyr_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 263687 bytes (257 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 257 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118432 bytes (115 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 115 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

* installing *source* package ‘dbplyr’ ...
** package ‘dbplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘[.fun_list’, ‘[.grouped_df’, ‘all.equal.tbl_df’, ‘anti_join.data.frame’, ‘anti_join.tbl_df’, ‘arrange.data.frame’, ‘arrange.default’, ‘arrange.grouped_df’, ‘arrange.tbl_df’, ‘arrange_.data.frame’, ‘arrange_.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.grouped_df’, ‘as.data.frame.rowwise_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_cube’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as.table.tbl_cube’, ‘as.tbl.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl.tbl’, ‘as.tbl_cube.array’, ‘as.tbl_cube.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl_cube.matrix’, ‘as.tbl_cube.table’, ‘as_data_frame.grouped_df’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_df’, ‘cbind.grouped_df’, ‘collapse.data.frame’, ‘collect.data.frame’, ‘common_by.NULL’, ‘common_by.character’, ‘common_by.default’, ‘common_by.list’, ‘compute.data.frame’, ‘copy_to.DBIConnection’, ‘copy_to.src_local’, ‘default_missing.data.frame’, ‘default_missing.default’, �� [... truncated]
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘dplyr.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dbplyr’
* removing ‘/home/aos11409/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dbplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘modelr’ ...
** package ‘modelr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘[.fun_list’, ‘[.grouped_df’, ‘all.equal.tbl_df’, ‘anti_join.data.frame’, ‘anti_join.tbl_df’, ‘arrange.data.frame’, ‘arrange.default’, ‘arrange.grouped_df’, ‘arrange.tbl_df’, ‘arrange_.data.frame’, ‘arrange_.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.grouped_df’, ‘as.data.frame.rowwise_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_cube’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as.table.tbl_cube’, ‘as.tbl.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl.tbl’, ‘as.tbl_cube.array’, ‘as.tbl_cube.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl_cube.matrix’, ‘as.tbl_cube.table’, ‘as_data_frame.grouped_df’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_df’, ‘cbind.grouped_df’, ‘collapse.data.frame’, ‘collect.data.frame’, ‘common_by.NULL’, ‘common_by.character’, ‘common_by.default’, ‘common_by.list’, ‘compute.data.frame’, ‘copy_to.DBIConnection’, ‘copy_to.src_local’, ‘default_missing.data.frame’, ‘default_missing.default’, �� [... truncated]
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘dplyr.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘modelr’
* removing ‘/home/aos11409/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/modelr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/aos11409/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpztQF5N/downloaded_packages’
```

Afterwards, tidyverse is not installed, and is not recognized. Is there a suggested way to install tidyverse under these conditions? Yes? No? Alternatives that have worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

There is an easier way: use already compiled binaries. See this [link](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) ([mirror](https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)) for more information

From your Linux terminal, run

```
$> echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or for `R 3.5.x`

```
$> echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add this key to your system with the command

```
$> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

After that

```
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get upgrade -y

$> sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-recommended r-base-dev
```

Search if the `tidyverse` is available

```
$> apt search r-cran-tidyverse
p   r-cran-tidyverse                - GNU R package "Easily Install and Load the
```

Installation

```
$> sudo apt-get install -y build-dep r-cran-tidyverse
```

Done !!!

---

I've recently installed the `tidyverse` package on my Linux Mint 19 which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic. This is what I did:

From your Linux terminal, run

```
$> sudo apt-get update

$> sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev r-recommended

$> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libgit2-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev libudunits2-dev libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

If you encounter `The following packages have unmet dependencies` error, try running the following to fix it

```
$> sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then in R/RStudio terminal

```
R> install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! But I'm now getting this problem:

`The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgit2-dev : Depends: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: And when I install it, and retry, I get the same error.

Comment: If you encounter unmet dependencies errors, try `sudo apt-get install -f` right after that. Linux will then install all required libs

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1291372/what-is-the-step-by-step-procedure-to-fix-the-the-following-packages-have-unmet

Comment: @Bucephalus: see my updated answer for an easier way

Comment: when I do as you specified, I get this:

`bucephalus@dumont:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: So the same problem seems to persist. The package it says "depends" appears to be installed according to terminal.

Comment: Turns out it was my R version that was causing the problem. I just installed a new R version and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed the system dependencies before installing tidyverse? If not, run

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

in terminal before you proceed with `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

For more details, read [this post](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: Perfect solution