# How to install Tidyverse on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) system, preferably in a maintainable way, such that I can execute the code examples in a related [book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/).

I've explored posted questions related to this one, and have found the top or accepted answers did not allow me to install Tidyverse.

[Install system packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719942/how-to-install-tidyverse-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-17-04)

[Use already compiled binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901581/installing-tidyverse-on-ubuntu-18-x-r-3-4-4-3-5-1)

[Install cran packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719942/how-to-install-tidyverse-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-17-04)

[Install readr without lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543983/non-zero-exit-when-installing-package-only-tidyverse)

[Install system packages (in comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812177/why-does-tidyverse-installation-not-find-packages-on-ubuntu)

[Using devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191416/trouble-installing-tidyverse-in-r)

So now I am trying to build up an installation procedure from a state where previously-mentioned packages begin uninstalled, which currently does not work but gives a template from which answers to this question can be modifications from.

1. `$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev`
2. `$ sudo apt-get install r-base-core r-base-dev`
3. `$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-curl r-cran-openssl r-cran-xml2`
4. `$ R`
5. `> install.packages("tidyverse")`

Following the above procedure ends with the following as output in the R interactive terminal:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 696 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
** package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘$.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘$.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘$.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘$<-.quosures’, ‘$<-.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘$<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.quosure’, ‘[.quosures’, ‘[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.rlang_envs’, ‘[.stack’, ‘[<-.quosures’, ‘[[.quosure’, ‘[[.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘[[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[[.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘[[<-.quosures’, ‘[[<-.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘[[<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘Math.quosure’, ‘Ops.quosure’, ‘Summary.quosure’, ‘as.character.quosure’, ‘as.list.quosures’, ‘c.quosures’, ‘c.rlang_envs’, ‘cnd_footer.default’, ‘cnd_header.default’, ‘conditionMessage.rlang_error’, ‘format.rlang_error’, ‘format.rlang_trace’, ‘length.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘length.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘length.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘mean.quosure’, ‘median.quosure’, ‘names.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘names.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘name [... truncated]
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: !!!, !!, %@%, %@%<-, %|%, %||%, :=, f_env<-, f_lhs<-, f_rhs<-, fn_body<-, fn_env<-, fn_fmls<-, fn_fmls_names<-, .data, UQ, UQS, abort, are_na, arg_match, as_box, as_box_if, as_bytes, as_character, as_closure, as_complex, as_data_mask, as_data_pronoun, as_double, as_env, as_environment, as_function, as_integer, as_label, as_list, as_logical, as_name, as_overscope, as_pairlist, as_quosure, as_quosures, as_string, as_utf8_character, base_env, bytes, bytes_along, bytes_len, call2, call_args, call_args_names, call_depth, call_fn, call_frame, call_inspect, call_modify, call_name, call_ns, call_stack, call_standardise, caller_env, caller_fn, caller_frame, calling, catch_cnd, child_env, chr, chr_along, chr_len, chr_unserialise_unicode, cnd, cnd_body, cnd_entrace, cnd_footer, cnd_header, cnd_message, cnd_muffle, cnd_signal, cnd_type, coerce_class, coerce_type, cpl, cpl_along, cpl_len, ctxt_depth, ctxt_frame, ctxt_stack, current_env, current_fn, current_frame, dbl, dbl_along, dbl_len, done, dots_definitions, dots_list, dots_n, dots_splice, dots_values, duplicate, empty_env, enexpr, enexprs, enquo, enquos, ensym, ensyms, entrace, env, env_bind, env_bind_active, env_bind_exprs, env_bind_fns, env_bind_lazy, env_binding_are_active, env_binding_are_lazy, env_binding_are_locked, env_binding_lock, env_binding_unlock, env_bury, env_clone, env_depth, env_get, env_get_list, env_has, env_inherits, env_is_locked, env_label, env_length, env_lock, env_name, env_names, env_parent, env_parents, env_poke, env_poke_parent, env_print, env_tail, env_unbind, env_unlock, error_cnd, eval_bare, eval_tidy, exec, exiting, expr, expr_deparse, expr_interp, expr_label, expr_name, expr_print, expr_text, exprs, exprs_auto_name, f_env, f_label, f_lhs, f_name, f_rhs, f_text, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_cpl, flatten_dbl, flatten_if, flatten_int, flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, fn_body, fn_env, fn_fmls, fn_fmls_names, fn_fmls_syms, format_error_bullets, frame_position, friendly_type, get_env, get_expr, global_env, global_frame, has_length, has_name, have_name, inform, inherits_all, inherits_any, inherits_only, int, int_along, int_len, interrupt, invoke, is_atomic, is_attached, is_bare_atomic, is_bare_bytes, is_bare_character, is_bare_double, is_bare_env, is_bare_environment, is_bare_formula, is_bare_integer, is_bare_integerish, is_bare_list, is_bare_logical, is_bare_numeric, is_bare_raw, is_bare_string, is_bare_vector, is_binary_lang, is_bool, is_box, is_bytes, is_call, is_call_stack, is_callable, is_character, is_chr_na, is_closure, is_condition, is_copyable, is_cpl_na, is_dbl_na, is_definition, is_dictionaryish, is_done_box, is_double, is_empty, is_env, is_environment, is_eval_stack, is_expr, is_expression, is_false, is_formula, is_formulaish, is_frame, is_function, is_installed, is_int_na, is_integer, is_integerish, is_interactive, is_lambda, is_lang, is_lgl_na, is_list, is_logical, is_missing, is_na, is_named, is_namespace, is_node, is_node_list, is_null, is_pairlist, is_primitive, is_primitive_eager, is_primitive_lazy, is_quosure, is_quosures, is_raw, is_reference, is_scalar_atomic, is_scalar_bytes, is_scalar_character, is_scalar_double, is_scalar_integer, is_scalar_integerish, is_scalar_list, is_scalar_logical, is_scalar_raw, is_scalar_vector, is_scoped, is_spliced, is_spliced_bare, is_stack, is_string, is_symbol, is_symbolic, is_syntactic_literal, is_true, is_unary_lang, is_vector, is_weakref, is_zap, lang, lang_args, lang_args_names, lang_fn, lang_head, lang_modify, lang_name, lang_standardise, lang_tail, last_error, last_trace, lgl, lgl_along, lgl_len, list2, list_along, list_len, ll, local_bindings, local_interactive, local_options, locally, maybe_missing, message_cnd, missing_arg, modify, mut_attrs, mut_node_caar, mut_node_cadr, mut_node_car, mut_node_cdar, mut_node_cddr, mut_node_cdr, mut_node_tag, na_chr, na_cpl, na_dbl, na_int, na_lgl, names2, new_box, new_call, new_character, new_character_along, new_complex, new_complex_along, new_data_mask, new_definition, new_double, new_double_along, new_environment, new_formula, new_function, new_integer, new_integer_along, new_language, new_list, new_list_along, new_logical, new_logical_along, new_node, new_overscope, new_quosure, new_quosures, new_raw, new_raw_along, new_weakref, node, node_caar, node_cadr, node_car, node_cdar, node_cddr, node_cdr, node_poke_caar, node_poke_cadr, node_poke_car, node_poke_cdar, node_poke_cddr, node_poke_cdr, node_poke_tag, node_tag, ns_env, ns_env_name, ns_imports_env, overscope_clean, overscope_eval_next, pairlist2, parse_expr, parse_exprs, parse_quo, parse_quos, parse_quosure, parse_quosures, peek_option, peek_options, pkg_env, pkg_env_name, prepend, prim_name, push_options, qq_show, quo, quo_expr, quo_get_env, quo_get_expr, quo_is_call, quo_is_lang, quo_is_missing, quo_is_null, quo_is_symbol, quo_is_symbolic, quo_label, quo_name, quo_set_env, quo_set_expr, quo_squash, quo_text, quos, quos_auto_name, raw_along, raw_len, rep_along, rep_named, restarting, return_from, return_to, rst_abort, rst_exists, rst_jump, rst_list, rst_maybe_jump, scoped_bindings, scoped_env, scoped_envs, scoped_interactive, scoped_names, scoped_options, search_env, search_envs, seq2, seq2_along, set_attrs, set_env, set_expr, set_names, signal, splice, squash, squash_chr, squash_cpl, squash_dbl, squash_if, squash_int, squash_lgl, squash_raw, stack_trim, string, switch_class, switch_type, sym, syms, trace_back, trace_length, type_of, unbox, vec_poke_n, vec_poke_range, warn, warning_cnd, with_abort, with_bindings, with_env, with_handlers, with_interactive, with_options, with_restarts, wref_key, wref_value, zap
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpXT3xFS/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

It is clear from the output that the binary matches the checksum, and that the issue is related to exporting what appear to be method names from a namespace. While I am familiar with the general problem of namespace conflicts, I am unsure what is exactly happening here.

I've also tried changing step 5 to `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`, which instead gives the following output:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rex’, ‘covr’, ‘feather’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rex_1.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 89430 bytes (87 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 87 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/covr_3.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 144119 bytes (140 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 140 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/feather_0.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 73812 bytes (72 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 72 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 696 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rex’ ...
** package ‘rex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘[.fseq’, ‘[[.fseq’, ‘print.fseq’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: %$%, %<>%, %>%, %T>%, n'est pas, add, and, debug_fseq, debug_pipe, divide_by, divide_by_int, equals, extract, extract2, freduce, functions, inset, inset2, is_greater_than, is_in, is_less_than, is_weakly_greater_than, is_weakly_less_than, mod, multiply_by, multiply_by_matrix, not, or, raise_to_power, set_colnames, set_names, set_rownames, subtract, undebug_fseq, use_series
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rex’
* removing ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rex’
* installing *source* package ‘feather’ ...
** package ‘feather’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Platform is little endian. Good.
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather-read.cpp -o feather-read.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather-types.cpp -o feather-types.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather-write.cpp -o feather-write.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/buffer.cc -o feather/buffer.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/feather-c.cc -o feather/feather-c.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/io.cc -o feather/io.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/metadata.cc -o feather/metadata.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/reader.cc -o feather/reader.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/status.cc -o feather/status.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/types.cc -o feather/types.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c feather/writer.cc -o feather/writer.o
ar rcs libfeather.a feather/buffer.o feather/feather-c.o feather/io.o feather/metadata.o feather/reader.o feather/status.o feather/types.o feather/writer.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o feather.so RcppExports.o feather-read.o feather-types.o feather-write.o -L. -lfeather -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/feather/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘.DollarNames.C++Object’, ‘.DollarNames.Module’, ‘print.bytes’, ‘format.Rcpp_stack_trace’, ‘str.Rcpp_stack_trace’, ‘print.Rcpp_stack_trace’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: Module, Rcpp.package.skeleton, populate, loadRcppModules, setRcppClass, loadRcppClass, loadModule, cppFunction, exposeClass, evalCpp, sourceCpp, compileAttributes, registerPlugin, RcppLdFlags, LdFlags, demangle, sizeof, cpp_object_initializer, cpp_object_dummy, Rcpp.plugin.maker, getRcppVersion
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘feather’
* removing ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/feather’
* installing *source* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
** package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘$.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘$.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘$.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘$<-.quosures’, ‘$<-.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘$<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.quosure’, ‘[.quosures’, ‘[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.rlang_envs’, ‘[.stack’, ‘[<-.quosures’, ‘[[.quosure’, ‘[[.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘[[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[[.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘[[<-.quosures’, ‘[[<-.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘[[<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘Math.quosure’, ‘Ops.quosure’, ‘Summary.quosure’, ‘as.character.quosure’, ‘as.list.quosures’, ‘c.quosures’, ‘c.rlang_envs’, ‘cnd_footer.default’, ‘cnd_header.default’, ‘conditionMessage.rlang_error’, ‘format.rlang_error’, ‘format.rlang_trace’, ‘length.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘length.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘length.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘mean.quosure’, ‘median.quosure’, ‘names.rlang_ctxt_pronoun’, ‘names.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘name [... truncated]
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: !!!, !!, %@%, %@%<-, %|%, %||%, :=, f_env<-, f_lhs<-, f_rhs<-, fn_body<-, fn_env<-, fn_fmls<-, fn_fmls_names<-, .data, UQ, UQS, abort, are_na, arg_match, as_box, as_box_if, as_bytes, as_character, as_closure, as_complex, as_data_mask, as_data_pronoun, as_double, as_env, as_environment, as_function, as_integer, as_label, as_list, as_logical, as_name, as_overscope, as_pairlist, as_quosure, as_quosures, as_string, as_utf8_character, base_env, bytes, bytes_along, bytes_len, call2, call_args, call_args_names, call_depth, call_fn, call_frame, call_inspect, call_modify, call_name, call_ns, call_stack, call_standardise, caller_env, caller_fn, caller_frame, calling, catch_cnd, child_env, chr, chr_along, chr_len, chr_unserialise_unicode, cnd, cnd_body, cnd_entrace, cnd_footer, cnd_header, cnd_message, cnd_muffle, cnd_signal, cnd_type, coerce_class, coerce_type, cpl, cpl_along, cpl_len, ctxt_depth, ctxt_frame, ctxt_stack, current_env, current_fn, current_frame, dbl, dbl_along, dbl_len, done, dots_definitions, dots_list, dots_n, dots_splice, dots_values, duplicate, empty_env, enexpr, enexprs, enquo, enquos, ensym, ensyms, entrace, env, env_bind, env_bind_active, env_bind_exprs, env_bind_fns, env_bind_lazy, env_binding_are_active, env_binding_are_lazy, env_binding_are_locked, env_binding_lock, env_binding_unlock, env_bury, env_clone, env_depth, env_get, env_get_list, env_has, env_inherits, env_is_locked, env_label, env_length, env_lock, env_name, env_names, env_parent, env_parents, env_poke, env_poke_parent, env_print, env_tail, env_unbind, env_unlock, error_cnd, eval_bare, eval_tidy, exec, exiting, expr, expr_deparse, expr_interp, expr_label, expr_name, expr_print, expr_text, exprs, exprs_auto_name, f_env, f_label, f_lhs, f_name, f_rhs, f_text, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_cpl, flatten_dbl, flatten_if, flatten_int, flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, fn_body, fn_env, fn_fmls, fn_fmls_names, fn_fmls_syms, format_error_bullets, frame_position, friendly_type, get_env, get_expr, global_env, global_frame, has_length, has_name, have_name, inform, inherits_all, inherits_any, inherits_only, int, int_along, int_len, interrupt, invoke, is_atomic, is_attached, is_bare_atomic, is_bare_bytes, is_bare_character, is_bare_double, is_bare_env, is_bare_environment, is_bare_formula, is_bare_integer, is_bare_integerish, is_bare_list, is_bare_logical, is_bare_numeric, is_bare_raw, is_bare_string, is_bare_vector, is_binary_lang, is_bool, is_box, is_bytes, is_call, is_call_stack, is_callable, is_character, is_chr_na, is_closure, is_condition, is_copyable, is_cpl_na, is_dbl_na, is_definition, is_dictionaryish, is_done_box, is_double, is_empty, is_env, is_environment, is_eval_stack, is_expr, is_expression, is_false, is_formula, is_formulaish, is_frame, is_function, is_installed, is_int_na, is_integer, is_integerish, is_interactive, is_lambda, is_lang, is_lgl_na, is_list, is_logical, is_missing, is_na, is_named, is_namespace, is_node, is_node_list, is_null, is_pairlist, is_primitive, is_primitive_eager, is_primitive_lazy, is_quosure, is_quosures, is_raw, is_reference, is_scalar_atomic, is_scalar_bytes, is_scalar_character, is_scalar_double, is_scalar_integer, is_scalar_integerish, is_scalar_list, is_scalar_logical, is_scalar_raw, is_scalar_vector, is_scoped, is_spliced, is_spliced_bare, is_stack, is_string, is_symbol, is_symbolic, is_syntactic_literal, is_true, is_unary_lang, is_vector, is_weakref, is_zap, lang, lang_args, lang_args_names, lang_fn, lang_head, lang_modify, lang_name, lang_standardise, lang_tail, last_error, last_trace, lgl, lgl_along, lgl_len, list2, list_along, list_len, ll, local_bindings, local_interactive, local_options, locally, maybe_missing, message_cnd, missing_arg, modify, mut_attrs, mut_node_caar, mut_node_cadr, mut_node_car, mut_node_cdar, mut_node_cddr, mut_node_cdr, mut_node_tag, na_chr, na_cpl, na_dbl, na_int, na_lgl, names2, new_box, new_call, new_character, new_character_along, new_complex, new_complex_along, new_data_mask, new_definition, new_double, new_double_along, new_environment, new_formula, new_function, new_integer, new_integer_along, new_language, new_list, new_list_along, new_logical, new_logical_along, new_node, new_overscope, new_quosure, new_quosures, new_raw, new_raw_along, new_weakref, node, node_caar, node_cadr, node_car, node_cdar, node_cddr, node_cdr, node_poke_caar, node_poke_cadr, node_poke_car, node_poke_cdar, node_poke_cddr, node_poke_cdr, node_poke_tag, node_tag, ns_env, ns_env_name, ns_imports_env, overscope_clean, overscope_eval_next, pairlist2, parse_expr, parse_exprs, parse_quo, parse_quos, parse_quosure, parse_quosures, peek_option, peek_options, pkg_env, pkg_env_name, prepend, prim_name, push_options, qq_show, quo, quo_expr, quo_get_env, quo_get_expr, quo_is_call, quo_is_lang, quo_is_missing, quo_is_null, quo_is_symbol, quo_is_symbolic, quo_label, quo_name, quo_set_env, quo_set_expr, quo_squash, quo_text, quos, quos_auto_name, raw_along, raw_len, rep_along, rep_named, restarting, return_from, return_to, rst_abort, rst_exists, rst_jump, rst_list, rst_maybe_jump, scoped_bindings, scoped_env, scoped_envs, scoped_interactive, scoped_names, scoped_options, search_env, search_envs, seq2, seq2_along, set_attrs, set_env, set_expr, set_names, signal, splice, squash, squash_chr, squash_cpl, squash_dbl, squash_if, squash_int, squash_lgl, squash_raw, stack_trim, string, switch_class, switch_type, sym, syms, trace_back, trace_length, type_of, unbox, vec_poke_n, vec_poke_range, warn, warning_cnd, with_abort, with_bindings, with_env, with_handlers, with_interactive, with_options, with_restarts, wref_key, wref_value, zap
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’
ERROR: dependency ‘rex’ is not available for package ‘covr’
* removing ‘/home/galen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/covr’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpGxNQPL/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘rex’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘feather’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Given the above context, how can I change the above installation procedure such that it is easily maintained with package managers?

Additional Notes:

RStudio is not installed on my system.
R version information after installation with `apt-get`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: likely need to update your R version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably first update R (currently it is version 3.6.1-2). The documentation on how to set new repositories for R in Ubuntu is here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/